# Python Twisted multithreaded TCP proxy

Tags: python, twisted

I am trying to write a TCP proxy using Python's twisted framework. I started with the Twisted's port forward example and it seems to do the job in a standard secnario. The problem is that I have a rather peculiar scenario. What we need to so is to process each TCP data packet and look for a certain pattern.

In case the pattern matches we need to do a certain process. This process takes anywhere between 30-40 seconds (I know its not a good design but currently thats how things stand). The trouble is that if this process starts all other packets get held up/stuck till the process completes. So if there are 100 live connections and even if 1 of them calls the process all the remaining 99 processes are stuck.

Is there a standard 'twisted' way wherein each connection/session is handled in a separate thread so that the 'blocking process' does not intervene with the other live connections?

Example Code:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.protocols import portforward
from twisted.internet import threads


def processingOperation(data)
# doing the processing operation here
        sleep(30)
        return data

def server_dataReceived(self, data):

        if data.find("pattern we need to test")<> -1:
                data = processingOperation(data)

        portforward.Proxy.dataReceived(self, data)
portforward.ProxyServer.dataReceived = server_dataReceived

def client_dataReceived(self, data):

        portforward.Proxy.dataReceived(self, data)
portforward.ProxyClient.dataReceived = client_dataReceived
reactor.listenTCP(8383, portforward.ProxyFactory('xxx.yyy.uuu.iii', 80))

reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of cause there is. You defer the processing to a thread. For example:

```
def render_POST(self, request):
    # some code you may have to run before processing

    d = threads.deferToThread(method_that_does_the_processing, request)

    return ''
```

There is a trick: This will return before the processing is done. And the client will get the answer back. So you might want to return 202/Accepted instead of 200/Ok (or my dummy `''`).

If you need to return *after* the processing is complete, you can use an inline call-back (http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.2.0/api/twisted.internet.defer.inlineCallbacks.html).

Comment: Thanks Klaus, I am investigating this, Although I tried deferred once but am not an expert on it. I am working on it. In the meanwhile I am posting the sample portforward code I am using. As you can see I am calling processingOperation based on a pattern match. Maybe I am asking for too much but could you give some pointers with context to this code? As in where exactly inlinecalls would sit?

Comment: You don't need inlineCallbacks.  If you want to run some code in a thread, you only need deferToThread.

Comment: Thanks Klaus and Jean-Paul deferToThread did the trick. I did struggle however a bit with how the data flows between the various calls and how I may return the processed value, but in the end it worked. Many Thanks!